# Mongoose Model.updateMany not replacing an array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm having difficulty replacing a field with mongoose/mongodb

I have some documents that look like this:

```
{account:1234, myArray:[a,b,c]}
```

```
const newArray = [d,e,f];

const result = await Model.updateMany({
    account:1234,
  }, {
    $set:{
      // 'testUpdating':4,
      'myArray':newArray,
    }
  });
```

I get this back as a result:

```
{
 "ok": 0,
 "n": 0,
 "nModified": 0
}
```

However if i uncomment the `testUpdating:4` update, i get the expected result of having updated 18k documents, however only the 'testUpdating' field was modified.

I'm either doing something wrong, or it's just refusing to update the array field with a new array.

Comment: What is the value/type for a, b, c, d, e, f? From what I see, n: 0 means there is no matching document, are you sure that the document with `account:1234` really exist? https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/query.html#Query.prototype.updateMany()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Model.updateMany()` looks fine and should update all matching documents with your desired result.

This is probably a case of schema definition issues.

Make sure you define your `myArray` property with an array of types you actually want and you need to pass those data types to your `updateMany`. For example, if your `myArray` is an array of strings your schema will look similar to this:

```
const schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    account: {
        type: Number
    },
    testUpdating: {
        type: Number
    },
    myArray: [String] //< An array of strings i.e. ['a', 'b', 'c']

});
```

Then when you do your `updateMany` make sure you pass in an an array of strings like this:

```
const newArray = ['d', 'e', 'f']; //< An array of strings

const result = await Model.updateMany({
    account:1234,
}, {
   $set:{
     'testUpdating':4,
     'myArray':newArray,
   }
});
```

If you want to store an array of different types (not strings) then look at the [docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#arrays) for an example of options available.

Comment: Yep, turns out another developer had overwritten the updateMany function, so i wasn't going nuts after all!

Comment: @CadeEmbery Hope they bought you a coffee!

Answer (score 0):

**Example with** `update()` **is working:**

`upsert : true` means If record in not found **then record will be created**.
`upsert : false` means if record is not found then **record will not be created**.

In basic terms it is `insert + update = upsert`

`multi:true` to update **multiple documents** whereas `multi:false` it will update **single document**.

#### Data:

```js
   [
      {
        account: 1234,
        myArray: ["a","b","c"]
      },
       {
        account: 1234,
        myArray: ["a","b","c"]
      }
    ]
```

#### Update Aggregate:

```js
db.collection.update({
  "account": 1234
},
{
  "$set": {
    "myArray": [
      "d",
      "e",
      "f"
    ]
  }
},
{
  "multi": true,
  "upsert": false
})
```

#### Output:

```js
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
    "account": 1234,
    "myArray": [
      "d",
      "e",
      "f"
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000001"),
    "account": 1234,
    "myArray": [
      "d",
      "e",
      "f"
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out a co-worker had overridden the updateMany function which explains the weirdness.